# How I can change text of button 'Add to cart'?

Tags: magento-2.1.7

I want to change text of button '`Add to cart`' to '`Shop now`' .

How and where I can do this ? because I want to **change it in full website**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your theme you will get this `en_US.csv` file at below location

```
app\design\frontend\Infortis\base\i18n\en_US.csv
```

There you can put your custom translations, Like `Add to Cart` to `"Shop now"`

**Keep your cache disabled** or clear the cache.

Comment: manoj bro can you check this one ? https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/197422/place-data-in-a-specific-div-on-product-page   . I am badly stuck on this one

Comment: let me see , will check and revert , please refine your question its little hard to understand

Comment: kindly check now.

Answer (score 1):

Just add a override the default translation for "Add to Cart" to "Shop now".

You can do that for the English language in the file

```
app/design/frontend/YourTheme/ThemePackage/i18n/en_US.csv
```

Answer (score 1):

> Magento translates words and phrases when all of the following
>   conditions are met:
>
> The Magento code base has the necessary translation dictionaries for a
>   language This language is configured by the store administrator to be
>   used in specified scope (that is, storefront) The Magento application
>   automatically assembles translation dictionaries located in modules’
>   i18n directory into a dictionary per language. For example, Brazilian
>   Portuguese (pt_BR) translation dictionaries might be located in module
>   and theme directories similar to the following:

**app/code/Magento/Checkout/i18n/pt_BR.csv**

> app/design/frontend/Magento/demo/i18n/pt_BR.csv Assembling the
>   preceding pt_BR.csv files across all modules and the current theme
>   results in a Portuguese translation of the entire application area
>   (storefront or the Admin).
>
> for more detail : 
>   http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/frontend-dev-guide/translations/xlate.html

Answer (score 1):

Create a file with the name **en_US.csv** at the location `app/design/frontend/your_theme/theme_package/i18n/en_US.csv`
At there put this in your **.csv file**

```
"Add to Cart","Check Out"
```

You can put what ever thing you want instead.