# Magento2 : Place data in a specific div on product page

Tags: magento2

On product page I have a div its html is

```
<div class="product-secondary-column custom-sidebar-right grid12-12 no-right-gutter">
            <div class="inner">    
            </div>
        </div>
```

I want to place a attribute datain this div  `no-right-gutter` . Its occurring after  `Product.info.main`  on product page.

And reference container which I want to place is here and its xml is . I am trying like this

```
<referenceContainer name="no.right.gutter" > 
<block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Attributes" template="Magento_Catalog::product/view/topattributes.phtml" name="product.info.topattribute" destination="no.right.gutter" after="product.info.main" /> 
</referenceContainer>
```

So How can I place my data inside `no.right.gutter`

> Catalog_product_view.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?> 

<!-- 
<page layout="1column" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd"> 
--> 
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd"> 
<body> 
<referenceContainer name="content" > 

<block class="Infortis\Base\Block\Product\View" name="product-view-wrapper" template="product/view.phtml" before="-"> </block> 
<container name="container_product_image_1" label="Product View, Image Column" /> 
<container name="container_product_primary_1" label="Product View, Primary Column, Container 1" /> 
<container name="container_product_primary_2" label="Product View, Primary Column, Container 2" /> 
<container name="container_product_secondary_1" label="Product View, Secondary Column, Container 1" /> 
<container name="container_product_secondary_2" label="Product View, Secondary Column, Container 2" /> 
<container name="container_product_lower_primary_1" label="Product View, Lower Primary Column, Container 1" /> 
<container name="container_product_lower_primary_2" label="Product View, Lower Primary Column, Container 2" /> 
<container name="container_product_lower_secondary_1" label="Product View, Lower Secondary Column, Container 1" /> 
<container name="container_product_lower_secondary_2" label="Product View, Lower Secondary Column, Container 2" /> 
<!-- Static blocks --> 



<block class="Magento\Cms\Block\Block" name="block_product_secondary_bottom"> 
<arguments> 
<argument name="block_id" xsi:type="string">block_product_secondary_bottom</argument> 
</arguments> 
</block> 
</referenceContainer> 
<!-- Reset attributes of main containers --> 
<referenceContainer name="product.info.main" htmlTag="" htmlClass="" before="-" /> 
<referenceContainer name="product.info.media" htmlTag="" htmlClass="" after="product.info.main" /> 
<!-- Insert product view blocks into the new product view wrapper --> 
<move element="product.info.main" destination="product-view-wrapper" /> 
<move element="product.info.media" destination="product-view-wrapper" /> 
<move element="bundle.options.container" destination="product-view-wrapper" /> 
<move element="product.info.details" destination="product-view-wrapper" /> 
<move element="catalog.product.related" destination="product-view-wrapper" /> 
<move element="product.info.upsell" destination="product-view-wrapper" /> 

<!-- Move some blocks to new positions --> 
<!-- <move element="product.info.stock.sku" destination="product.info.price" after="product.price.final" /> --> 
<!-- <move element="product.info.social" destination="product.info.main" after="-" /> --> 
<move element="product.info.overview" destination="product.info.main" before="product.info.price" /> 
<move element="container_product_primary_1" destination="product.info.main" after="page.main.title" /> 
<move element="container_product_primary_2" destination="product.info.main" after="-" /> 
<!-- Move some blocks outside the "product.info.main" to manipulate their position inside template file --> 
<move element="product.info.weight" destination="product-view-wrapper" before="product.info.review" /> 
<move element="page.main.title" destination="product-view-wrapper" /> 


<move element="page.top.border" destination="product-view-wrapper" /> 

<move element="product.info.review" destination="product-view-wrapper" /> 
<!-- Product collateral data (tabs) --> 
<referenceBlock name="product.info.details" template="Infortis_Base::product/view/details.phtml" > <arguments> 
<argument translate="true" name="title" xsi:type="string">Kit Components</argument> 
<argument name="show_tabs" xsi:type="helper" helper="Infortis\Base\Helper\Template\Catalog\Product\View::showTabs" /> 
</arguments> 
<!-- Custom static blocks as tabs --> 
<block class="Magento\Cms\Block\Block" name="product_cms_block1" group="detailed_info"> 
<arguments> 
<argument name="block_id" xsi:type="string">block_product_tab1</argument> 
<argument name="title" xsi:type="helper" helper="Infortis\Base\Helper\Template\Catalog\Product\View::getStaticBlockTitle"> 
<param name="id">block_product_tab1</param> 
</argument> 
</arguments> 
</block> 
<block class="Magento\Cms\Block\Block" name="product_cms_block2" group="detailed_info"> 
<arguments> 
<argument name="block_id" xsi:type="string">block_product_tab2</argument> 
<argument name="title" xsi:type="helper" helper="Infortis\Base\Helper\Template\Catalog\Product\View::getStaticBlockTitle"> 
<param name="id">block_product_tab2</param> 
</argument> 
</arguments> 
</block> 
</referenceBlock> 

<referenceBlock name="product.info.main"> 
<block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View" name="share" template="product/view/share.phtml" /> 
</referenceBlock> 



<referenceBlock name="catalog.product.related" > 
<action method="setTemplate"> 
<argument name="template" xsi:type="helper" helper="Infortis\Base\Helper\Template\Catalog\Product\View::getRelatedProductsTemplate" /> 
</action> 
</referenceBlock> 
<referenceBlock name="product.info.upsell" hide="true"> 
<action method="setTemplate"> 
<argument name="template" xsi:type="helper" helper="Infortis\Base\Helper\Template\Catalog\Product\View::getUpsellProductsTemplate" /> 
<!-- TODO: --> 
<argument name="is_responsive" xsi:type="string">false</argument> 
<argument name="show_items" xsi:type="string">3</argument> 
</action> 
</referenceBlock> 
<referenceBlock name="checkout.cart.crosssell" hide="true"> 
<action method="setTemplate"> 
<argument name="template" xsi:type="string">Infortis_Base::product/list/slider.phtml</argument> 
</action> 
</referenceBlock> 


<referenceContainer name="no.right.gutter"> 
<block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Attributes" template="Magento_Catalog::product/view/topattributes.phtml" name="product.info.topattribute" after="-"/>  
</referenceContainer> 




<move element="reviews.tab" destination="main.content" after="-"/> 

<referenceBlock name="product.info.description"> 
<action method="setTitle"> 
<argument name="title" xsi:type="string">Highlights</argument> 
</action> 
</referenceBlock> 

<move element="share" destination="product.info.main" after="product.info.price" /> 



</body> 
</page>
```

I am hovering on div where I want to add attribute data.

[image: image where to add image]

Comment: Share your product page XML code as well

Comment: Could you share screen shot of page , pointing out where you want to place and where it is currently

Comment: @ManojDeswal  kindly check now

Comment: I ll see and revert you soon

Comment: is it  "no.right.gutter"  referenceContainer , or you created it ?... I check in default ultimo and there is no such container, first you need to create than you can reference to it

Comment: I created it , before it I was using  product.info.main  and it was coming in 12-6 grid under the product info. So I want it to come outer of this

Comment: bascially I want it to come outside of 'product.info.main'   so that I can place thing freely @ManojDeswal

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/67177/discussion-between-manoj-deswal-and-learner).