# How can i translate shipping address and order summary text in magento2

Tags: magento2, knockoutjs

I an not able to translate  Shipping address, Order summary text in Magento 2
[image]

Comment: in your custom theme change in "app/design/frontend/vendor-name/theme-name/i18n/en_US.csv"  https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/197342/54588

Comment: i am able to translate all page except checkout page.i already translate other pages but i don't understand why it does not work for checkout.

Comment: Okay , you translated other page and failed on these pages... then try module specific translations in your Magento_Checkout module

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try with Inline Translations

**Stores → Configuration → Advanced → Developer → Translate Inline → Enable for Storefront → Yes**

Comment: Thanks for giving such a perfect answer. Now i face the problem in some places there is no option for translate the like go to checkout.                                                             You  can check from this url:-
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BxP8SHsaiC2NX2o2MWVQMXBCNzA/view?usp=drivesdk                       can you please know where is this language.xml file located?